# My if statements will not take new values

Tags: java

The object is to get the average of the entered values. 
It is to stop when a negative number is entered.
I am trying to get the smallest and largest values entered.
The problem I am having is that my if statements will not take the smallest/largest new values entered.
It just gives me the `Integer.Max_Value` and `Integer.Min_Value`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargeSmallAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double count = 0;
    double amtOfNums = 0;
    int input = 0;
    int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE, largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int number;

    System.out.println("Enter a series of numbers. Enter a negative number to quit.");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while ((input = scan.nextInt()) > 0) {
        count += input;
        amtOfNums++;
    } 
    while(input>=0){
    for(int counter=1; counter<amtOfNums; counter++){
        number=scan.nextInt();

            if(number<smallest)
                smallest=number;

            if(number>largest)
                largest=number; 
    }
    }
    System.out.println("You entered " + amtOfNums + " numbers averaging " + (count/amtOfNums) + ".");
    System.out.println("The smallest number is "+ smallest);
    System.out.println("The largest number is " + largest);
}
}
```

Comment: All you're doing until the user enters a negative number is summing the numbers and counting them. You're then asking the user for numbers *again*, calling `scan.nextInt`, and not changing your loop condition. If you wanted to find the smallest and largest numbers, you'll need to keep track of that in your *first* `while` loop... it sounds like you should only have *one* loop for entering numbers.

Comment: @user2004685: Check what the initial values are for `smallest` and `largest`... it's fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, my bad! :)

Comment: Please explain your thinking on the how the `while(input>=0)` loop works? `input` can never be `> 0`, because that is the test in the previous loop. If user enters a negative number, the `while(input>=0)` loop will not execute at all. If user enters zero, the loop will run forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you have *two* loops. One sums the numbers, and the other finds the largest and smallest numbers. Given your output, it sounds like you should be doing it all in one loop - ideally with more useful variable names too. (Your `count` is actually a sum, not a count... and there's no need for it to be a `double`. You could make it a `long` if you really want to avoid overflow. Yes, you need to perform floating point arithmetic for your average, but you can do that *when you take the average*... your sum is logically an integer.)

```
int sum = 0;
int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int count = 0;   
while ((input = scan.nextInt()) >= 0) {
    count++;
    sum += input;
    // Alternative: smallest = Math.min(smallest, input)
    if (input < smallest) {
        smallest = input;
    }
    // Alternative: largest = Math.max(smallest, input)
    if (input > largest) {
        largest = input;
    }
} 
// Cast for count is just to force floating point division.
System.out.println("You entered " + count +
    " numbers averaging " + (sum / (double) count) + ".");
System.out.println("The smallest number is "+ smallest);
System.out.println("The largest number is " + largest);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your while loop condition: `while(input>=0){`

here input will be always less than zero due to your previous while statement:`while ((input = scan.nextInt()) > 0)`

Here while loop exits only when you enter a number which is less than zero.. so input will have that value..